# How can I give a rolling effect to a text with the hover?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, hover

The hover effect I'm trying to create for the link Resume.

What I'm trying to do is make a rolling effect when hover effect is applied to the resume link.

When the user applies the hover effect, the resume text will roll back and replace it with resume text with the color #ffc107.

In the code I wrote, a resume text with the color #ffc107 sits on top of the black one with the effect of coming from below. There is no effect as if the black colored resume text is rolling backwards. How can I create this?

```css
.nav-item .nav-link span {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

.nav-item .nav-link:hover span {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  color: #ffc107;
}

.nav-item .nav-link span:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  content: attr(data-hover);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.nav-item .nav-link:hover span:before {
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm container">
  <img class="navbar-brand" src="/assets/8726390_user_icon.svg" alt="">
  <div class="navbar-title-container">
    <span class="navbar-title" ,>CKY</span>
  </div>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
          <span data-hover="Resume">Resume</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```